# flv video URL streaming in iPhone Application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, webview, flv

Thanks in Advance.

I want to play `flv` `video` in my Application,How can I do it?is there any code to play `flv` video from url in `iphone` Application?

I am using following code for this.

```
NSString* embedHTML = @"\
        <html><head>\
        <style type=\"text/css\">\
        body {\
            background-color: transparent;\
        color: white;\
        }\
        </style>\
        </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
        <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body></html>";
        NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, webViewObj.frame.size.width, webViewObj.frame.size.height];
        [self.webViewObj loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't play an flv video in your iphone. Apple doesnt support it. So if you want to play this videos, then convert it to another formats in the server side. That is the best solution for this problem.